# How to add .vcs file to Android Calendar

Tags: android, calendar, icalendar

I went through this [SO forum and it says to add a header to the `.vcs` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825221/add-calendar-event-to-android-from-web-vcs-download) but when I try to open the `.vcs` file by clicking on it an Android system popup comes to open the `.vcs` file and Image, Video, Audio... but it does not added to the local **Android Calendar**.

Can any one help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.vcs` is very old for today usage. I recommend you to create newer version `.ics` file instead of `.vcs` and try the following;

```
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=london2012.ics");
```

See [Difference between iCalendar (.ics) and the vCalendar (.vcs)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1310420/1847645)

Comment: Strange, I'm using the php icalcreator class and I'm having this problem as well. I checked the code for the header output and it's as shown above. But on the Android, I only get the generic options described above.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, .ics or .vcs are not handled by default on android however on samsung devices it actually starts the 'S planner' application